# Issue - Unknown CMake command "list_append_unique"

Tags: catkin, cmake, catkin-make

Base path: /Users/arghymu/my-robotics-system/catkin_ws
Source space: /Users/arghymu/my-robotics-system/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /Users/arghymu/my-robotics-system/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /Users/arghymu/my-robotics-system/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /Users/arghymu/my-robotics-system/catkin_ws/install

Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/Users/arghymu/my-robotics-system/catkin_ws/build"
CMake Error at /Users/arghymu/miniconda3/envs/ROS/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:95 (list_append_unique):
Unknown CMake command "list_append_unique".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/arghymu/my-robotics-system/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
make: *** [Makefile:268: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1

Comment: We need some more context on your problem. From afar, it looks like there is some sort of command that is not found. I'd suggest you to upload the CMakeLists file for your package so that we can understand better.